# C# Threading program | Regarding thread.join

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In the below program why the t.join functionality is not working. It will continue to type character O on the screen even when i have specified it to wait for the another thread to complete.

```
class Program
{
    bool done;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => Go('U'));

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.Write('O');
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        t.Start();
        t.Join();

        Console.WriteLine("Thread t has ended!");
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void Go(char p)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        { 
            Console.Write(p);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to your program, the main thread prints all the O's and only then starts the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never started the second thread - you're printing out `O`s, but you only start the second thread after you're done with that (in about eight minutes).

Move the `t.Start();` *before* the loop, and it should work the way you expect it to work.

Don't guess around with multi-threading - it's incredibly easy to get subtly wrong. Learn what a thread is, what does `Join` do, and how to use multiple threads safely. Otherwise, you'll have a lot of fun debugging issues that are near impossible to reproduce and fix :)